# How to add .Net 6 localization structure to area?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to apply localization structure to area.

[image]

But is not working.
It is working in general project but is not working when I tried for the area named dashboard.

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: You need to provide more details like how you configure localization in `program.cs`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.